# Сокращённая форма выдачи автокомплита

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

господа!
Прошу Вас помочь с решением моей проблемы, и так: есть очень длинное слово в автокомплите, как его можно обрезать и вместо оканчания вставить `...`

Пример: сейчас -`ActionScriptttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\111`

Надо- `ActionScriptttttt....\111`.

Конкретнее, надо что бы в поле ввод полностью влазила сокращенная инфа из автокомплита.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScriptttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\111",
      "AppleScript\222",
      "Asp\333",
      "BASIC\444",
      "C\555",
      "C++\666",
      "Clojure\777",
      "COBOL\888",
      "ColdFusion\999",
      "Erlang\10000",
      "Scheme\111111"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags" >Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" style="width:100px;">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

```css
.ui-widget-content .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
    max-width: 200px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScriptttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\111",
      "AppleScript\222",
      "Asp\333",
      "BASIC\444",
      "C\555",
      "C++\666",
      "Clojure\777",
      "COBOL\888",
      "ColdFusion\999",
      "Erlang\10000",
      "Scheme\111111"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags" >Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" style="width:100px;">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Думаю как вариант, попробуйте:

```
availableTags = $.map(availableTags, function(val, i) {
  return val.replace(val.substring(12, val.lenght), '...'); //после 12 позиции заменяем на ....
});
```